If my suggested edit is canceled, there should not be a notice saying my edit is rejected
When I suggested an edit in Mathematics Stack Exchange, my suggested edit was canceled due to “This edit conflicted with a subsequent edit.” By community bot.
Due to my canceled edit, when I click “edit” on any questions or answers, they will show an “attention” notice like the picture below:
.

Attention! Your last edit was rejected. While reasonable edits may be rejected for many reasons outside of your control, you should review the reasons given for rejecting it before continuing.

But, there is a problem with the notice: my edit was cancelled, not rejected.
I think that the “attention” notice should not be shown, or the notice should be changed to say “suggested edits canceled”.
This bug still happens after the design for suggested edits page have changed: Where are the popups like “How to tag” and “How to format” when editing questions on sites where I have <2000 reputation?

@Mat My edit was canceled before my account suspended.

If you kept cancelling edits, that's a bad thing too. While the 'letter' of the warning is incorrect, and cancelling an edit is 'in' your hands, the reminder that you should consider your suggested edits is probably valid.

Related: Dismiss suggested edits which conflict with full edit instead of auto rejecting them

Looking at the cancelled edit, you absolutely should be reviewing it. Your edit misses another rather obvious instance of the thing you fixed (all caps).

Update 2 October:
Unfortunately, this bug seems like regressed again once the design for suggested edits page has changed: Where are the popups like “How to tag” and “How to format” when editing questions with sites where I have reputation <2000?
See the picture below:

that says:

Attention! Your last edit was rejected. While reasonable edits may be rejected for many reasons outside of your control, you should review the reasons given for rejecting it before continuing.

But the edit was canceled not rejected.

29 September 2024
10 minutes ago, I just suggest an edit on Mathematics Stack Exchange, and my edit is canceled by the “Community” bot.
When I clicked the “edit” button on random posts after my previous edit was canceled, there is no “Attention!” notice says that my edit was rejected.




The recent visual updates did not include any logic changes in regards to cancelled edits and the notice shown. I don't think that's a regression, since the original issue reported was never addressed or fixed. This issue remains separate.
