Where are the popups like “How to tag” and “How to format” when editing questions on sites where I have <2000 reputation?
See the pictures to compare the differences on the Suggested Edits page of now and before. (I show the suggested edit's rejected version, as there are small changes on it).
Now (the change happened to me today.)



Before



Are there some unannounced changes?

What I'm wondering about is, where are the popups, like “How to tag”, and “How to format”?
Now (when editing questions):



Now (when editing answers):



Now (How to tag?)



Before (How to tag?) (Taken for this question)



Question: Where did the popups like “How to tag” and “How to format” that show up when editing questions on sites where I have <2000 reputation go?

We recently made visual updates to the notices on the suggested edits page. This should not have have affected/removed any of content on the right sidebars. I'll get the team that did the fix to look into this.

@Carrott And see my answer here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/401544/if-my-suggested-edit-is-canceled-there-should-not-be-a-notice-saying-my-edit-is

Just confirmed with the team, this issue was not related to the recent banner changes but was introduced in July it seems. We'll log it as a bug and it will get prioritized with the others.
